# Replace pandoc Markdown citeproc references in html DOM by citations and add bibliography with citeproc-js

Tags: csl, citation-js, citeproc-js

Dears,

I create compliance reports with nodejs and pug. Historically, we have Markdown templates with Pandoc citerproc blocks that previously were processed by pandoc-citeproc, but now I try to reduce the dependencies and use citeproc-js (or citation.js) instead.

Our document has paragraphs such as:

```html
<p>Cookie consent management is therefore the means through which web service users can <strong>express, reject and withdraw their consent</strong> to accessing or storing information on or related to their device in line with @regulation20181725, art. 37; @eprivacydirective, art. 5(3)</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum [See in this respect @edpb:guidelines012020, paras. 14 and 15] Lorem ipsum [See in this respect @edpb:cookiebannertaskforce2023, paras 2, 23, 24; @edpb:guidelines052020, para. 7]</p>
```

I have developed the following javacript based on citeproc-js to:

1. iterate over all p elements and match all brackets `[…]`
2. iterate over the bib items in the brackets (one or more)
3. call citeproc-js and replace the bracket by a number
4. call citeproc-js to generate a bibliography

Unfortunately, my understanding of `citationsPre` and `citationsPost` is too poor to understand how I generate the number and the bibliography. ([docs](https://citeproc-js.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html#processcitationcluster))

My code:

```js
let endnoteIndex = 0;
// const regexpGroup = new RegExp(/\[((;?(?:[^;@\]]*)@[^;@\]]+)+)\]/,"g"); // first capture group is content in brackets
const regexpGroup = new RegExp(/\[([^\]\n]*@[^\]\n]+)\]/,"g"); // first capture group is content in brackets
const regexpRef = new RegExp(/(?<prefix>[^@]*)@(?<id>[^,]+)(,(?<post>.*))?/); // capture pretext, id, postext

const style = document.getElementById('citeproc-csl-style').textContent;
const locale = document.getElementById('citeproc-locale').textContent;
const bibliographyArray = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('citeproc-csl-bib').textContent);
let bibliography = {};
for (item of bibliographyArray) {
  bibliography[item.id] = item;
}

const citeprocSys = {
  retrieveLocale: function (lang) {
    return locale;
  },
  retrieveItem: function (id) {
    let item = bibliography[id];
    if(!item) throw new Error(`Bibliography item ${id} not found.`);
    return item;
  }
}

let citeproc = new CSL.Engine(citeprocSys, style);

let citationsPre = [];
let citationsPost = [];

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement
function replacer(match, refsString) {
  console.log(refsString);
  let citationItems = refsString.replaceAll('&nbsp;',' ').split(';').map( refString => {
    let refData = refString.trim().match(regexpRef).groups;
    // https://citeproc-js.readthedocs.io/en/latest/csl-json/markup.html#cite-items
    let ref = {
      id: refData.id,
      // CSL Locator list https://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#locators
      /*
      locator: 12,
      label: "page",
      */
      prefix: refData.prefix,
      suffix: refData.suffix
    }
    return ref;
  });
  
  let citations = {
    citationItems: citationItems,
    properties: {
      // In the properties portion of a citation, the noteIndex value indicates the footnote number in which the citation is located within the document.
      // Citations within the main text of the document have a noteIndex of zero.
      noteIndex: 0
    }
  }
  
  let result;
  try {
    result = citeproc.processCitationCluster(citations, citationsPre, citationsPost);
    citationsPre.push(...[]);
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error);
    return match;
  }
  
  endnoteIndex += 1;
  // return `<a href="#endnote-${endnoteIndex}">[${endnoteIndex}]</a>`;
  return `<a href="#endnote-${endnoteIndex}">${result[1][0][1]}</a>`;
}

function findReferences(paragraph) {
  paragraph.innerHTML = paragraph.innerHTML.replaceAll(regexpGroup, replacer);
}

// find references in all paragraphs
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p'), findReferences);

let bibResult = citeproc.makeBibliography();
console.log("bibresult", bibResult);
document.getElementById('bibliography').innerHTML = bibResult[0].bibstart+bibResult[1].join('\n')+bibResult[0].bibend;
```

The output bib has always only the last item. What's missing here?
Another issue I face is that URLs are plain-text instead of clickable.

[image: screenshot of bibliograhpy with only one element]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working. For the record here my solution.

A few comments ahead:

- I made this work with the [Oscola](https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=oscola) CSL style. It creates citations meant to be footnotes and does not assume a bibliography in the document. As HTML has no real footnotes, I sided for endnotes. Those endnotes refer to each other (e.g. "{short title} (n. 12)" means the long references is in endnote 12).
- The array `endnoteArray` stores all received notes and I integrate updates coming in from `citeproc.processCitationCluster`.
- `citeproc.processCitationCluster` calls a method to add to my `citation` object the property `citationID`.
- in the `citationsPre` array, I need to start numbering from 1 upwards, because that the endnote number that oscola uses and oscola assumes numbering starts with 1
- I replace every finding of a pandoc-formatted citation not with the citation, but with my own counter `endnoteIndex`, which is like footnote/endnote number. Pandoc+biblatex would do this step automatically when configured for footnote citations (`\autocite{ref}` with `autocite=footnote`).

Thanks to LarsW who put me into the right direction.

```js
let endnoteIndex = 0;
let endnoteArray = [];
// const regexpGroup = new RegExp(/\[((;?(?:[^;@\]]*)@[^;@\]]+)+)\]/,"g"); // first capture group is content in brackets
const regexpGroup = new RegExp(/\[([^\]\n]*@[^\]\n]+)\]/,"g"); // first capture group is content in brackets
const regexpRef = new RegExp(/(?<prefix>[^@]*)@(?<id>[^,]+)(,(?<suffix>.*))?/); // capture pretext, id, postext

const style = document.getElementById('citeproc-csl-style').textContent;
const locale = document.getElementById('citeproc-locale').textContent;
const locale_fallback = document.getElementById('citeproc-locale-fallback').textContent;
const bibliographyArray = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('citeproc-csl-bib').textContent);
let bibliography = {};
for (item of bibliographyArray) {
  bibliography[item.id] = item;
}

const citeprocSys = {
  retrieveLocale: function (lang) {
    if(lang == 'en-US') return locale_fallback;
    return locale;
  },
  retrieveItem: function (id) {
    let item = bibliography[id];
    if(!item) throw new Error(`Bibliography item ${id} not found.`);
    return item;
  }
}

let citeproc = new CSL.Engine(citeprocSys, style);

let citationsPre = [];
let citationsPost = [];

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement
function replacer(match, refsString) {
  console.log(refsString);
  let citationItems = refsString.replaceAll('&nbsp;',' ').split(';').map( refString => {
    let refData = refString.trim().match(regexpRef).groups;
    // https://citeproc-js.readthedocs.io/en/latest/csl-json/markup.html#cite-items
    let ref = {
      id: refData.id,
      // CSL Locator list https://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#locators
      /*
      locator: 12,
      label: "page",
      */
      prefix: refData.prefix || undefined,
      suffix: refData.suffix
    }
    return ref;
  });

  let citation = {
    citationItems: citationItems,
    properties: {
      // In the properties portion of a citation, the noteIndex value indicates the footnote number in which the citation is located within the document.
      // Citations within the main text of the document have a noteIndex of zero.
      noteIndex: 0,
    }
  }

  let result;
  try {
    result = citeproc.processCitationCluster(citation, citationsPre, citationsPost);
    // console.log("citationID", citation.citationID);
    citationsPre.push([
      // endnote number starting from 1
      citation.citationID, endnoteIndex+1,
    ]);
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(result[1], null, 2));
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error);
    return match;
  }

  result[1].forEach(e => {
    endnoteArray[e[0]] = e[1];
  });
  endnoteIndex += 1;
  // citations here will be numbered and linked as endnotes
  return `<sup><a href="#endnote-${endnoteIndex}" id="ref-${endnoteIndex}">(${endnoteIndex})</a></sup>`;
  // normally (check whether instead of [1][0] another item must be chosen)
  // return `<a href="#endnote-${endnoteIndex}">${result[1][0][1]}</a>`;
}

function findReferences(paragraph) {
  paragraph.innerHTML = paragraph.innerHTML.replaceAll(regexpGroup, replacer);
}

// find references in all paragraphs
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p'), findReferences);

let bibResult = citeproc.makeBibliography();
console.log("bibresult", bibResult);
// citations are added as endnotes
document.getElementById('bibliography').innerHTML = bibResult[0].bibstart+endnoteArray.map((e,i) => `<div id="endnote-${i+1}" class="csl-entry">${e.replaceAll(/&#60;(.*?)&#62;/mg, (match,url) => `<a href="${url}" target="_blank">${url}</a>`).replaceAll(/\((n (\d+))\)/mg, (match,note,ref) => `(<a href="#endnote-${ref}">${note}</a>)`)} <a href="#ref-${i+1}">↩︎</a></div>`).join('\n')+bibResult[0].bibend;
// normally, bibliography is printed
// document.getElementById('bibliography').innerHTML = bibResult[0].bibstart+bibResult[1].join('\n')+bibResult[0].bibend;
```

[image: screenshot of endnotes with Oscola CSL]

Answer (score 0):

With [`citationsPre`](https://citeproc-js.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html#processcitationcluster) permanently set to `[]`, citeproc-js assumes you are updating the first citation cluster, and removes the publication that was previously there from the internal registry. To fix this, you could (as a start) replace the following code:

```js
citationsPre.push(...[]);
```

with:

```js
citationsPre.push([
  // result[1] are the citation clusters that have changed,
  // result[1][0] is the first cluster.
  result[1][0][2], // cluster id
  result[1][0][0], // note number
]);
```

However, that does not fix the code entirely.

- Citations that are introduced later may change citation clusters that have been rendered before. This might not apply to endnote styles, but might still affect your code. Namely, `result[1]` contains *all* citation clusters that possibly changed. To get the "correct" (new) rendered citation you therefore probably cannot use `result[1][0][1]`, you need to track the citation cluster IDs (`result[1][*][2]`) in conjunction with `citationsPre`.
- The links will probably not work as expected if a single cluster contains multiple references. You seem to only include one citation per cluster though.
- citeproc-js always expects the `en-US` locale to be available, as it is the final step in [locale fallback in CSL](https://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#locale-fallback).

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I am pushing now the data as in your code example. This leads to many errors: `TypeError: this.registry.citationreg.citationById[preCitation[0]] is undefined`. Any clue?

Also, my little example text snippets contains multiple references in a single cluster: `[See in this respect @edpb:cookiebannertaskforce2023, paras 2, 23, 24; @edpb:guidelines052020, para. 7]`

I understand that I have to iterate twice over all references to get tracking right. Would I win something if changing to citation.js?

Comment: I'm not sure about the errors without an example that I can debug. I missed the example with multiple references. You'd want to link to individual entries in the bibliography right? Yes, you'd probably have to iterate twice. Citation.js does not change that.